# Find the volume of this space/solid

Tags: calculus, integration, proof-writing

There is a function $z=f(x, y)$ where f is a continuous function and $f \geq 0$ in the region $D$.

Taverage value, $\bar{z}$ is $\dfrac{1}{\text{Area of }D}\iint_D f(x, y)dA$.

At the same time, $s \geq 0$ is a constant where $D=\{(x, y):x^2+y^2\leq s^2\}$.

Question: how do I show that the volume of the object that is below $z=f(x,y)$ and above $D$ (so it is between z and D) is equal to the volume of a cylinder of radius $s$ and height $\bar{z}$.

Now, this seems to intuitively make sense, since this in-between volume of $z$ and $f(x,y)$ seem to form a cylinder. The only problem is, we don't know $f(x,y)$. It could be anything.

The first step that I'm taking is trying to prove this using a double integral. This double integral will calculate the volume in between $z$ and $D$. Is this a good place to start? If so, what do I do next?

Comment: Based on your specification of $D$, the cylinder has radius $s$, not $R$.

Comment: You can compute the minimum and maximum of $f$ on $D$, so $\int\int_D f$ is between Area$(D)$ times the minimum and Area$(D)$ times the maximum.  Then use the intermediate value theorem...

Comment: Usually one writes $\iint_D$ or $\iint\limits_D$ rather than $\int\int_D$ in this context, i.e. `\iint` rather than `\int\int`. $\qquad$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $\bar z$ is defined as:

$$\bar z =\frac{\iint_D z\ dA}{A_D}$$

Where $A_D$ is the area of the region $D$

Then the volume of the solid between $z$ and the $xy$-plane over the region $D$ is

$$V_1=\iint_D z\ dA$$

And the volume of the cylinder with height $\bar z$ over the same region is

$$ V_2=A_D\bar z=A_D\frac{\iint_D z\ dA}{A_D}$$
$$=\iint_D z\ dA$$

Thus the two volumes are the same.